# clone of drupal project failing: operation timed out

Tags: version-control

I am trying to clone the drupal project locally  but getting this error

```
k10593:htdocs welcha$ git clone git://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git fooproject
Cloning into 'fooproject'...
fatal: unable to connect to drupalcode.org:
drupalcode.org[0: 140.211.10.6]: errno=Operation timed out
```

I am following this tutorial: http://drupal.org/node/803746

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: It may seem like an obvious question, but have you checked basic network connectivity on this server? Is drupalcode.org resolved? "host drupalcode.org"

Comment: Do you use proxy to connect to the internet? If yes then you might need to do a `export http_proxy=<proxy_server>:<port>` from your terminal.

Comment: You are cloning from the wrong url.
It is git://git.drupal.org/project/drupal.git
for drupal core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disconnecting your wifi and then connecting again. Used to resolve the issue before, when i got "some broken pipe error". This generally happen iF your wifi network keep switching to different connection to balance the load. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There is some connection issues.
Try it once again after disconnecting your wifi.

Now go to you github account http://www.github.com
Now search for the project that you want to clone.

then go for forking.

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo (what is forking and it works.)

there is a fork button on the top right side of your github account.Click that button. It would copy the project in your github account.

Now go for **git clone (ssh url of the project)**